# SQL NOT BETWEEN query

Tags: mysql, sql, between

Thanks in advance for any advice or tips!

I have a booking table in a mysql database, `table1`. It contains a start date and a finish date.
I have another table, `table2` which contains the information I need to get but only when a specific date does NOT reside between any of the dates from any rows in `table1`.

An example;

```
select table2.testfield
FROM table2, table1
WHERE '2011-02-24 18:00:00'
NOT BETWEEN table1.start 
AND table1.finish
```

However I cannot get it to work! Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the link from table1 to table2? I think the where clause needs a condition to link table1 to table2, so for example WHERE ('2011-02-24 18:00:00' NOT BETWEEN table1.start AND table1.finish) AND (table1.testfield = table2.testfield)

Comment: I assume table2 has more than one row. Which one of them do you want to compare to table1.testfield? (The odds are good that table1.testfield will be between some of the start and end dates, and not between some other start and end dates.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work but should look something more like

```
select table2.testfield
FROM table2, table1
WHERE table1.YourField = '2011-02-24 18:00:00' 
AND
NOT BETWEEN table1.start AND table1.finish
```

This also presumes that your `table1.start` and `table1.finish` fields are of type `DateTime`. If they aren't you could try Casting the fields

```
select table2.testfield
    FROM table2, table1
    WHERE table1.YourField = '2011-02-24 18:00:00' 
    AND
    NOT BETWEEN Cast(table1.start as DateTime) AND Cast(table1.finish As DateTime)
```

**Edit** Looking at your question I realized that the date probably isn't a database value :) so your method should work but you may need to cast the string to a datetime.

Comment: Thats right my date will be a ever changing variable not stored in the database. My method works but only for the first row in table1, which contains multiple booking entries.Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 3):

Something like this then?

```
select table2.testfield
FROM table2, table1
WHERE 
   table1.start > convert(datetime,'2011-02-24 18:00:00')
   or table1.finish < convert(datetime,'2011-02-24 18:00:00')
```