# mysql query for give array in the date not into interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have some query:

```
$dataStart = '02-02-2014 ; 
$dataEnd = '02-03-2014 ; //[$dataStart , $dataEnd ]  $dataStart (less then) $dataEnd
```

I want to  select  all  data from database that not  in this interval or part of this interval between this data i don't need to  be selected.

```
( [S_ADATE, S_DDATE ] );
```

this what  i made   :

```
$query = ( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE  S_ADATE > $dataEnd OR S_DDATE < $dataStart ') ;
```

but if part of interval  i don't want it , how can add this queryto  this..

Comment: When you say `part of interval i dont want it` do you mean that you want to exclude a range of dates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL NOT BETWEEN query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106466/sql-not-between-query)

Comment: 'part of interval' it's mean if  $dataStart between [S_ADATE, S_DDATE ]  or $dataEnd between  [S_ADATE, S_DDATE ]  i don't want to  be selected.

Comment: SQL NOT BETWEEN query  @paqogomez  can you  created with  this example i post, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If I understand this problem correctly, what you want is
```

that the startdate or end date should not fall in the interval of s_adate and s_ddate.

```
        Try this:

        select * from table where ($datestart  NOT BETWEEN s_adate and s_ddate) OR($enddate NOT BETWEEN s_adate and s_ddate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query might look this way

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE s_ddate NOT BETWEEN '2014-02-02' AND '2014-03-02'
   AND s_adate NOT BETWEEN '2014-02-02' AND '2014-03-02'
```

php part

```
$dataStart = '2014-02-02' ; 
$dataEnd = '2014-03-02' ;
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM table 
         WHERE s_ddate NOT BETWEEN $dataStart AND $dataEnd
           AND s_adate NOT BETWEEN $dataStart AND $dataEnd";
```

**Note:**

1. use proper date literals `'YYYY-MM-DD'`
2. use prepared statements instead of interpolating query strings

Comment: can you  create full  query  with addition i have in post (wit this : $query = ( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE  S_ADATE > $dataEnd OR S_DDATE < $dataStart ') ) and complete it with  your post.