# Trying to SELECT everything but excluding between IDs doesnt work

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to SELECT everything but not between the 6 id and 12 id but it doesn't work it only returns everything

Here is my code:

```
SELECT nom FROM genre WHERE id_genre BETWEEN id_genre=!6 AND id_genre=!12;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL NOT BETWEEN query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106466/sql-not-between-query)

Comment: you should use > and <

Comment: Use [Not between](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-between)

Comment: use <> instead =! ... WHERE id_genre<>6 AND id_genre<>12; ... no need BETWEEN

Answer (score 0):

When you write condtition `WHERE id BETWEEN 6 AND 12`, what you want is to find those `id`s that are greater or equal than 6 and less or equal than 12, i.e. `id >= 6 AND id <= 12`.

Now, you want to negate it, so you'd write (accordingly to mathematical logic rules): `id < 6 OR id > 12`, which means you want `id`s outside this range.

Or, you could write simply: `NOT (id BETWEEN 6 AND 12)`.