# How to use the MySQL NOT EXISTS operator

Tags: mysql, datetime, not-exists

On the table `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` I divided the days into time slots of one hour each, e.g. 2020-04-14

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
| start_date          | end_date            | sID |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
| 2020-04-14 00:00:00 | 2020-04-14 00:59:00 |   1 |
| 2020-04-14 01:00:00 | 2020-04-14 01:59:00 |   2 |
| 2020-04-14 02:00:00 | 2020-04-14 02:59:00 |   3 |
| 2020-04-14 03:00:00 | 2020-04-14 03:59:00 |   4 |
| 2020-04-14 04:00:00 | 2020-04-14 04:59:00 |   5 |
| 2020-04-14 05:00:00 | 2020-04-14 05:59:00 |   6 |
| 2020-04-14 06:00:00 | 2020-04-14 06:59:00 |   7 |
| 2020-04-14 07:00:00 | 2020-04-14 07:59:00 |   8 |
| 2020-04-14 08:00:00 | 2020-04-14 08:59:00 |   9 |
| 2020-04-14 09:00:00 | 2020-04-14 09:59:00 |  10 |
| 2020-04-14 10:00:00 | 2020-04-14 10:59:00 |  11 |
| 2020-04-14 11:00:00 | 2020-04-14 11:59:00 |  12 |
| 2020-04-14 12:00:00 | 2020-04-14 12:59:00 |  13 |
| 2020-04-14 13:00:00 | 2020-04-14 13:59:00 |  14 |
| 2020-04-14 14:00:00 | 2020-04-14 14:59:00 |  15 |
| 2020-04-14 15:00:00 | 2020-04-14 15:59:00 |  16 |
| 2020-04-14 16:00:00 | 2020-04-14 16:59:00 |  17 |
| 2020-04-14 17:00:00 | 2020-04-14 17:59:00 |  18 |
| 2020-04-14 18:00:00 | 2020-04-14 18:59:00 |  19 |
| 2020-04-14 19:00:00 | 2020-04-14 19:59:00 |  20 |
| 2020-04-14 20:00:00 | 2020-04-14 20:59:00 |  21 |
| 2020-04-14 21:00:00 | 2020-04-14 21:59:00 |  22 |
| 2020-04-14 22:00:00 | 2020-04-14 22:59:00 |  23 |
| 2020-04-14 23:00:00 | 2020-04-14 23:59:00 |  24 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
24 rows in set
```

Now I need to find in a second table for the time slots missing with respect to table `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020`

This the [tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-exists/)

The code I've tried below without success

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `calendar_recovery_table_time_slot_2020`;

INSERT IGNORE INTO `calendar_recovery_table_time_slot_2020` SELECT
    start_date,
    end_date,
    NULL
FROM
    `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` t
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            `stable_2020` m
        WHERE
            m.`sdatetime` BETWEEN t.start_date
        AND t.end_date
        AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(m.`sdatetime`, ' ', 1) = '2020-04-14'
        ORDER BY
            m.`sdatetime` DESC
    )
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(start_date, ' ', 1) = '2020-04-14';
```

my version of MySQL is 5.5.62-log

the name of column is sDatetime the type is Datetime.

any suggestion, please?

thanks in advance for any help

**Update**

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar_recovery_table_time_slot_2020` (
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`),
  KEY `start_date` (`start_date`),
  KEY `end_date` (`end_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` (
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE `stable_2020` (
  `STUX` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ukey` (`STUX`,`sdatetime`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `sdatetime` (`sdatetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Update 2**

```
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 00:00:00', '2020-4-14 00:59:00', 1);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 01:00:00', '2020-4-14 01:59:00', 2);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 02:00:00', '2020-4-14 02:59:00', 3);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 03:00:00', '2020-4-14 03:59:00', 4);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 04:00:00', '2020-4-14 04:59:00', 5);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 05:00:00', '2020-4-14 05:59:00', 6);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 06:00:00', '2020-4-14 06:59:00', 7);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 07:00:00', '2020-4-14 07:59:00', 8);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 08:00:00', '2020-4-14 08:59:00', 9);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 09:00:00', '2020-4-14 09:59:00', 10);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 10:00:00', '2020-4-14 10:59:00', 11);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 11:00:00', '2020-4-14 11:59:00', 12);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 12:00:00', '2020-4-14 12:59:00', 13);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 13:00:00', '2020-4-14 13:59:00', 14);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 14:00:00', '2020-4-14 14:59:00', 15);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 15:00:00', '2020-4-14 15:59:00', 16);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 16:00:00', '2020-4-14 16:59:00', 17);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 17:00:00', '2020-4-14 17:59:00', 18);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 18:00:00', '2020-4-14 18:59:00', 19);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 19:00:00', '2020-4-14 19:59:00', 20);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 20:00:00', '2020-4-14 20:59:00', 21);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 21:00:00', '2020-4-14 21:59:00', 22);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 22:00:00', '2020-4-14 22:59:00', 23);
INSERT INTO calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 (`start_date`, `end_date`, `sID`) VALUES ('2020-4-14 23:00:00', '2020-4-14 23:59:00', 24);
```

Comment: Can you share table structure for calendar_recovery_table_time_slot_2020 and calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020

Comment: @AmanKumayu Only structure ? Please see my question update

Comment: I presume you know you have a minute missing at the end of each hour, right? Your rows run from the top of each hour to one minute before the top of the next hour.

Comment: @O.Jones Yes Sir, it's no coincidence it's desired... thanks

Comment: stable_2020 for this table also? can you share structure

Comment: It would help if you show some sample rows from your `calendar_recovery...` table and your desired result set.

Comment: @AmanKumayu Ok, ready in my question update

Comment: @O.Jones the structure is in  in my question **update** you need rows value?

Comment: Yes, please, actual sample row values help clarify questions a lot.

Comment: @UncleVince so you need to find out time slots which are missing in  stable_20 table from table calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 ?

Comment: @AmanKumayu exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add NOT BETWEEN operator in your SQL Query like this:

```
SELECT
            1
        FROM
            `stable_2020` m
        WHERE
            m.`sdatetime` NOT BETWEEN t.start_date
        AND t.end_date
        AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(m.`sdatetime`, ' ', 1) = '2020-04-14'
        ORDER BY
            m.`sdatetime` DESC
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106466/sql-not-between-query) is another solution.

This way you will never need NOT EXISTS operator in your query. Try this and let me know, Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for this help