# SQL NOT BETWEEN syntax in query on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join

On the table `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` I divided the days into time slots of one hour each, e.g. `2020-04-14`

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
| start_date          | end_date            | sID |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
| 2020-04-14 00:00:00 | 2020-04-14 00:59:00 |   1 |
| 2020-04-14 01:00:00 | 2020-04-14 01:59:00 |   2 |
| 2020-04-14 02:00:00 | 2020-04-14 02:59:00 |   3 |
| 2020-04-14 03:00:00 | 2020-04-14 03:59:00 |   4 |
| 2020-04-14 04:00:00 | 2020-04-14 04:59:00 |   5 |
| 2020-04-14 05:00:00 | 2020-04-14 05:59:00 |   6 |
| 2020-04-14 06:00:00 | 2020-04-14 06:59:00 |   7 |
| 2020-04-14 07:00:00 | 2020-04-14 07:59:00 |   8 |
| 2020-04-14 08:00:00 | 2020-04-14 08:59:00 |   9 |
| 2020-04-14 09:00:00 | 2020-04-14 09:59:00 |  10 |
| 2020-04-14 10:00:00 | 2020-04-14 10:59:00 |  11 |
| 2020-04-14 11:00:00 | 2020-04-14 11:59:00 |  12 |
| 2020-04-14 12:00:00 | 2020-04-14 12:59:00 |  13 |
| 2020-04-14 13:00:00 | 2020-04-14 13:59:00 |  14 |
| 2020-04-14 14:00:00 | 2020-04-14 14:59:00 |  15 |
| 2020-04-14 15:00:00 | 2020-04-14 15:59:00 |  16 |
| 2020-04-14 16:00:00 | 2020-04-14 16:59:00 |  17 |
| 2020-04-14 17:00:00 | 2020-04-14 17:59:00 |  18 |
| 2020-04-14 18:00:00 | 2020-04-14 18:59:00 |  19 |
| 2020-04-14 19:00:00 | 2020-04-14 19:59:00 |  20 |
| 2020-04-14 20:00:00 | 2020-04-14 20:59:00 |  21 |
| 2020-04-14 21:00:00 | 2020-04-14 21:59:00 |  22 |
| 2020-04-14 22:00:00 | 2020-04-14 22:59:00 |  23 |
| 2020-04-14 23:00:00 | 2020-04-14 23:59:00 |  24 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
24 rows in set
```

Now I need to find in a second table `stable_2020` for the time slots missing with respect to table `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020`

```
+------+---------------------+-----+
| STUX | sdatetime           | sID |
+------+---------------------+-----+
|   14 | 2020-04-14 01:09:00 |   1 |
|   14 | 2020-04-14 01:59:00 |   2 |
|   14 | 2020-04-14 02:02:00 |   3 |
|   14 | 2020-04-14 02:52:00 |   4 |
+------+---------------------+-----+
4 rows in set
```

This the [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106466/sql-not-between-query)

On this example I need the output below, because on `stable_2020` I have four rows

Two rows on time slot

```
| 2020-04-14 01:00:00 | 2020-04-14 01:59:00 |   2 |
```

Other two rows on time slot

```
| 2020-04-14 02:00:00 | 2020-04-14 02:59:00 |   3 |
```

output required

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| start_date          | end_date            |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2020-04-14 00:00:00 | 2020-04-14 00:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 03:00:00 | 2020-04-14 03:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 04:00:00 | 2020-04-14 04:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 05:00:00 | 2020-04-14 05:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 06:00:00 | 2020-04-14 06:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 07:00:00 | 2020-04-14 07:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 08:00:00 | 2020-04-14 08:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 09:00:00 | 2020-04-14 09:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 10:00:00 | 2020-04-14 10:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 11:00:00 | 2020-04-14 11:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 12:00:00 | 2020-04-14 12:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 13:00:00 | 2020-04-14 13:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 14:00:00 | 2020-04-14 14:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 15:00:00 | 2020-04-14 15:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 16:00:00 | 2020-04-14 16:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 17:00:00 | 2020-04-14 17:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 18:00:00 | 2020-04-14 18:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 19:00:00 | 2020-04-14 19:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 20:00:00 | 2020-04-14 20:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 21:00:00 | 2020-04-14 21:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 22:00:00 | 2020-04-14 22:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 23:00:00 | 2020-04-14 23:59:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The code I've tried below without success

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT
    t.start_date,
    t.end_date
FROM
    `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` t,
    `stable_2020` m
WHERE
    m.`sdatetime` NOT BETWEEN Cast(t.start_date AS DateTime)
AND Cast(t.end_date AS DateTime);
+---------------------+---------------------+
| start_date          | end_date            |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2020-04-14 00:00:00 | 2020-04-14 00:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 01:00:00 | 2020-04-14 01:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 02:00:00 | 2020-04-14 02:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 03:00:00 | 2020-04-14 03:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 04:00:00 | 2020-04-14 04:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 05:00:00 | 2020-04-14 05:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 06:00:00 | 2020-04-14 06:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 07:00:00 | 2020-04-14 07:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 08:00:00 | 2020-04-14 08:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 09:00:00 | 2020-04-14 09:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 10:00:00 | 2020-04-14 10:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 11:00:00 | 2020-04-14 11:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 12:00:00 | 2020-04-14 12:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 13:00:00 | 2020-04-14 13:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 14:00:00 | 2020-04-14 14:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 15:00:00 | 2020-04-14 15:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 16:00:00 | 2020-04-14 16:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 17:00:00 | 2020-04-14 17:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 18:00:00 | 2020-04-14 18:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 19:00:00 | 2020-04-14 19:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 20:00:00 | 2020-04-14 20:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 21:00:00 | 2020-04-14 21:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 22:00:00 | 2020-04-14 22:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 23:00:00 | 2020-04-14 23:59:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
24 rows in set
```

And

```
mysql> SELECT
    start_date,
    end_date
FROM
    `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` t
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            `stable_2020` m
        WHERE
            m.`sdatetime` NOT BETWEEN t.start_date
        AND t.end_date
        ORDER BY
            m.`sdatetime` DESC
    );
+---------------------+---------------------+
| start_date          | end_date            |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2020-04-14 00:00:00 | 2020-04-14 00:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 01:00:00 | 2020-04-14 01:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 02:00:00 | 2020-04-14 02:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 03:00:00 | 2020-04-14 03:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 04:00:00 | 2020-04-14 04:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 05:00:00 | 2020-04-14 05:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 06:00:00 | 2020-04-14 06:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 07:00:00 | 2020-04-14 07:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 08:00:00 | 2020-04-14 08:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 09:00:00 | 2020-04-14 09:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 10:00:00 | 2020-04-14 10:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 11:00:00 | 2020-04-14 11:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 12:00:00 | 2020-04-14 12:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 13:00:00 | 2020-04-14 13:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 14:00:00 | 2020-04-14 14:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 15:00:00 | 2020-04-14 15:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 16:00:00 | 2020-04-14 16:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 17:00:00 | 2020-04-14 17:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 18:00:00 | 2020-04-14 18:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 19:00:00 | 2020-04-14 19:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 20:00:00 | 2020-04-14 20:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 21:00:00 | 2020-04-14 21:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 22:00:00 | 2020-04-14 22:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 23:00:00 | 2020-04-14 23:59:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
24 rows in set
```

My structure table below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stable_2020`;
CREATE TABLE `stable_2020` (
  `STUX` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ukey` (`STUX`,`sdatetime`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `sdatetime` (`sdatetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of stable_2020
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `stable_2020` VALUES ('14', '2020-04-14 01:09:00', '1');
INSERT INTO `stable_2020` VALUES ('14', '2020-04-14 01:59:00', '2');
INSERT INTO `stable_2020` VALUES ('14', '2020-04-14 02:02:00', '3');
INSERT INTO `stable_2020` VALUES ('14', '2020-04-14 02:52:00', '4');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020`;
CREATE TABLE `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` (
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 00:00:00', '2020-04-14 00:59:00', '1');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 01:00:00', '2020-04-14 01:59:00', '2');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 02:00:00', '2020-04-14 02:59:00', '3');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 03:00:00', '2020-04-14 03:59:00', '4');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 04:00:00', '2020-04-14 04:59:00', '5');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 05:00:00', '2020-04-14 05:59:00', '6');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 06:00:00', '2020-04-14 06:59:00', '7');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 07:00:00', '2020-04-14 07:59:00', '8');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 08:00:00', '2020-04-14 08:59:00', '9');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 09:00:00', '2020-04-14 09:59:00', '10');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 10:00:00', '2020-04-14 10:59:00', '11');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 11:00:00', '2020-04-14 11:59:00', '12');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 12:00:00', '2020-04-14 12:59:00', '13');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 13:00:00', '2020-04-14 13:59:00', '14');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 14:00:00', '2020-04-14 14:59:00', '15');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 15:00:00', '2020-04-14 15:59:00', '16');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 16:00:00', '2020-04-14 16:59:00', '17');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 17:00:00', '2020-04-14 17:59:00', '18');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 18:00:00', '2020-04-14 18:59:00', '19');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 19:00:00', '2020-04-14 19:59:00', '20');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 20:00:00', '2020-04-14 20:59:00', '21');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 21:00:00', '2020-04-14 21:59:00', '22');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 22:00:00', '2020-04-14 22:59:00', '23');
INSERT INTO `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` VALUES ('2020-04-14 23:00:00', '2020-04-14 23:59:00', '24');
```

**update**

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT
    t.start_date,
    t.end_date
FROM
    `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` t,
    `stable_2020` m
WHERE
    Cast(
        DATE_FORMAT(
            m.`sdatetime`,
            '%Y-%m-%d %H'
        ) AS DateTime
    ) NOT BETWEEN Cast(
        DATE_FORMAT(t.start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H') AS DateTime
    )
AND Cast(
    DATE_FORMAT(t.end_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H') AS DateTime
);
+---------------------+---------------------+
| start_date          | end_date            |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2020-04-14 00:00:00 | 2020-04-14 00:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 01:00:00 | 2020-04-14 01:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 02:00:00 | 2020-04-14 02:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 03:00:00 | 2020-04-14 03:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 04:00:00 | 2020-04-14 04:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 05:00:00 | 2020-04-14 05:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 06:00:00 | 2020-04-14 06:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 07:00:00 | 2020-04-14 07:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 08:00:00 | 2020-04-14 08:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 09:00:00 | 2020-04-14 09:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 10:00:00 | 2020-04-14 10:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 11:00:00 | 2020-04-14 11:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 12:00:00 | 2020-04-14 12:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 13:00:00 | 2020-04-14 13:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 14:00:00 | 2020-04-14 14:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 15:00:00 | 2020-04-14 15:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 16:00:00 | 2020-04-14 16:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 17:00:00 | 2020-04-14 17:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 18:00:00 | 2020-04-14 18:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 19:00:00 | 2020-04-14 19:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 20:00:00 | 2020-04-14 20:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 21:00:00 | 2020-04-14 21:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 22:00:00 | 2020-04-14 22:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 23:00:00 | 2020-04-14 23:59:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
24 rows in set
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can left join `calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020` to `stable_2020` and return the unmatched rows:

```
SELECT c.start_date, c.end_date
FROM calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 c LEFT JOIN stable_2020 s
ON s.sdatetime BETWEEN c.start_date AND c.end_date
WHERE s.SID IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bgJBUArF79hreSkiWufHQa/0).
Results:

```
| start_date          | end_date            |
| ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 2020-04-14 00:00:00 | 2020-04-14 00:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 03:00:00 | 2020-04-14 03:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 04:00:00 | 2020-04-14 04:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 05:00:00 | 2020-04-14 05:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 06:00:00 | 2020-04-14 06:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 07:00:00 | 2020-04-14 07:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 08:00:00 | 2020-04-14 08:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 09:00:00 | 2020-04-14 09:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 10:00:00 | 2020-04-14 10:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 11:00:00 | 2020-04-14 11:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 12:00:00 | 2020-04-14 12:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 13:00:00 | 2020-04-14 13:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 14:00:00 | 2020-04-14 14:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 15:00:00 | 2020-04-14 15:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 16:00:00 | 2020-04-14 16:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 17:00:00 | 2020-04-14 17:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 18:00:00 | 2020-04-14 18:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 19:00:00 | 2020-04-14 19:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 20:00:00 | 2020-04-14 20:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 21:00:00 | 2020-04-14 21:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 22:00:00 | 2020-04-14 22:59:00 |
| 2020-04-14 23:00:00 | 2020-04-14 23:59:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just discard the minutes and seconds and compare the date time just on date and hour. So you dont need between.

This would be the work-out of what I mean:
You do a LEFT JOIN on the table "**stable_2020**" where the dates are the same and the hours are the same. And give only the results where no record is found in "**stable_2020**"

```
SELECT 
    t1.start_date, t1.end_date
FROM 
    calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    stable_2020 AS t2
ON 
    (DATE(t1.start_date) = DATE(t2.sdatetime)) 
    AND (HOUR(t1.start_date) = HOUR(t2.sdatetime))
WHERE 
    t2.SID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand your suggestion ... so sorry... please see **update** in this question

Answer (score 0):

I would use `not exists` for this:

```
select c.*
from calendar_recovery_interval_hour_2020 
where not exists (
    select 1 from stable_2020 s where s.datetime nto between c.start_date and c.end_date
)
```

With an index on `stable_2020(datetime)`, this query should have good performance.