# Get data from diffrent ranges from database in PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a products table and products are stored with width and height properties. for example

| id | width | height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 134 | 171 |
| 2 | 172 | 244 |
| 3 | 234 | 362 |
| 4 | 65 | 90 |

I have a filter so a user can filter the products by width and height. my problem is I want to get remaining all the products that are not in the range of filter in the `else` statement.
my code-

```
if (isset($_POST['product_size'])) {
  if ($_POST['product_size'] == '60x90') {
    $get_range = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_width BETWEEN 50 AND 70 AND product_height BETWEEN 70 AND 110 AND status = '1'";
  } elseif ($_POST['product_size'] == '80x120') {
    $get_range = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_width BETWEEN 70 AND 90 AND product_height BETWEEN 110 AND 140 AND status = '1'";
  } elseif ($_POST['product_size'] == '100x150') {
    $get_range = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_width BETWEEN 90 AND 110 AND product_height BETWEEN 140 AND 170 AND status = '1'";
  } elseif ($_POST['product_size'] == '120x180') {
    $get_range = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_width BETWEEN 110 AND 130 AND product_height BETWEEN 170 AND 200 AND status = '1'";
  } elseif ($_POST['product_size'] == '150x200') {
    $get_range = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_width BETWEEN 140 AND 160 AND product_height BETWEEN 200 AND 220 AND status = '1'";
  } elseif ($_POST['product_size'] == '170x240') {
    $get_range = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_width BETWEEN 160 AND 180 AND product_height BETWEEN 220 AND 260 AND status = '1'";
  } elseif ($_POST['product_size'] == '200x300') {
    $get_range = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_width BETWEEN 180 AND 240 AND product_height BETWEEN 260 AND 330 AND status = '1'";
  } elseif ($_POST['product_size'] == '250x350') {
    $get_range = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_width BETWEEN 240 AND 260 AND product_height BETWEEN 330 AND 370 AND status = '1'";
  } elseif ($_POST['product_size'] == 'super') {
    $get_range = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_width > 260 AND product_height > 370 AND status = '1'";
  } elseif ($_POST['product_size'] == 'special') {
    $get_range = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_width < 260 AND product_height > 370 AND status = '1'";
  } else {
    $get_range = "in this section I want to fetch all the products which does not fulfil the filter criteria";
  }
```

Thanks for your time and sorry for my English.

Comment: Select all products from the database and *then* sort the PHP array result depending on the criteria. OR run two MySQL queries which are opposites of each other. Also your set of `if/else` looks really combersome; you can build the SQL query dynamically and avoid all of that.

Comment: @Martin can you show me how to do that? I am learning :)

Comment: @Martin ???????

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to try and get the inverse of the query in an `if` statement in the `else` statement because the else and if are "mutually exclusive"; they will never both fire. So, your else should be all products or no products?

Comment: My answer was incorrect because I had missed your "super" and "special" options.

Comment: forgot about special super right now. let's say I have products of height 548 and more. how can I get those products

Comment: Basically, you need to use "BETWEEN" for getting the valuse between the points, and then using [MYSQL `NOT BETWEEN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857764/sql-not-between-syntax-in-query-on-mysql) for getting the opposite values, that are outside of these points. this should catch all of them (you may need an extra qualifier if there are any `null` values).